# Using CMD to find and count occurences?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

Simplification :

A long command yields  counts of occurences :

```
echo 2 | find /C "2" //output "1"
```

This is because "2" appears only once (per line) hence the output 1.

But now I want to `echo success` only if the value is **greater** than 1. ( else throw error)

something like this :

`echo 2 | find /C "2" | check if val >1 && echo "success" ELSE throw`

**Question:**

I've managed to do the left part. But How can I create the right section ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [conditional executing](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

If you only want to check, **if** a string occures at least once, you don't need `/c`:

```
echo 2|find "2" >nul && echo success || echo fail
```

For other numbers (e.g "more than one"), you need to count `/c` and to capture the output with a `for /f` loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%a in ('type "%~f0"^|find /c "e"') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
if %count% gtr 1 (
  echo more than one
) else (
  echo one or less
)
```

For demo, I search the batchfile itself and count the lines containing (at least one) `e`. A `for /f` loop is used to capture the output of a command into a variable, which you then can compare with another value.

Just for academic reasons, without a `for` loop:

```
type test.txt|find /c "2"|findstr /xv "0 1" >nul && echo more than one
```

This works in your special case, but the `for` loop is more generic.

(I know, you are aware of it, but to make clear for future readers: `find /c` counts *lines* that contain the search string (at least once), not *overall* occurrences)

Comment: I want more than once.the question states : _But now I want to echo success only if the value is *greater than 1*_